# Submenu is not getting visible on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, submenu

See my code and demo [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/y2hw5pca/) plz. I am not very used to with css but its simple, i have seen many demos working nearly with same code. But i am unable to catch the difference which is causing problem

I need a submenu to be opened under `UserForm` but its not getting visible on hover (using css)

Comment: You are using the CSS rule `#main_nav ul ul { top: 100% }`. This is placing the element off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Yes that is the answer actually.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove "top" and "left" from #main_nav ul ul like this:

```
#main_nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

It is because of how "position: absolute" works. In your case the parent "li" has "position: static" (default) and in that case "position: absolute" makes the child ul placed absolute in the entire document. You can see this if you just remove "visiblity: hidden" and then it is placed at the bottom of the page. Another solution is to set "position: relative" to the parent li

Comment: That's. right, could you plz explain why it should work only if i remove them. Whats the problem with positioning?

Comment: It is because of how "position: absolute" works. In your case the parent "li" has "position: static" (default) and in that case "position: absolute" makes the child ul placed absolute in the entire document. You can see this if you just remove "visiblity: hidden" and then it is placed at the bottom of the page. Another solution is to set "position: relative" to the parent li.